# Filtering value and combining results in one

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've list of multiple dataframes and am trying to filter multiple values in a column based on a condition.

```
list = [df1,df2,df3,df4]             # multiple dataframes
grp_list = [con, eco, dip, pol]      # multiple categories in a column 

for i in list: 
if i['pgp'].isin(group_list) and (i.egp == i.pgp):
    i['value'] = 1
elif ~i['pgp'].isin(group):
    i['value'] = 2
else:
    0

df1:
pgp     egp     value
con     con      1     # return 1 if pgp value is in the element list & pgp = egp
eco     eco      1     
dip     health   0     # else 0
pol     health   0
god     con      2
ent     eco      2     # return 2 if pgp value is not in the element list
```

Comment: If possible, can you please add a sample data for us to reproduce, and your expected output? Thanks

Comment: @KevinChoonLiangYew I figured out the above output which is working fine. But, I have one question if you can help me with is how can I use "not in" operator for the list elements?  ...................df1 = df['Pgp'].notin(group_list) ........ using this I'm getting error

Comment: You can always do `(~df['Pgp'].isin(group_list))` it's the same as what you were expecting

Comment: @KevinChoonLiangYew - I've updated my question above. Its not working while combining all together. Any suggestions where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

There are some improvements you can do to your code. Firstly, don't use `list` as your variable as it is already a built-in function in Python. Secondly, you can always create a list of result and then add it back into the column.

```
list_ = [df1,df2,df3,df4]             # multiple dataframes
grp_list = ['con', 'eco', 'dip', 'pol']      # multiple categories in a column 


for i in list_: 
    result = []
    for row_pgp, row_egp in zip(i['pgp'], i['egp']):
        if row_pgp in grp_list and row_pgp == row_egp:
            result.append(1)
        elif row not in grp_list and row_egp in grp_list:
            result.append(2)
        else:
            result.append(0)
    
    i['value'] = result
```